# Adjust the img height according to div height

Tags: html, css

I came across this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USZXa/40/) that I thought would work for my project.

HTML:

```
<div>
     <header>
         <div>XXX</div>
     </header>
     <main>
         <div>
             <div class="content"></div>
         </div>
     </main>
     <footer>
         <div>YYY</div>
     </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .container, .table {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.table > div {
    display: table-row;
}

.table > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#header,#footer {
    height: 1px;
}
```

What I wanted to do was to add an image within the < div class="content" > where the image's height would follow the div's height even after resizing the window. Could that be done without pushing the footer down?

Thanks!

Comment: See this codepen for fully-responsive image (css only): http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/DpmnK

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your css:

```
.content img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```